# Is the following weak version of second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture already known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Very recently I was going through my previous MSE posts and I stumbled upon some of them regarding the [Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) which states that,

> For all $x,y\ge 2$ we have, $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)\ge \pi(x+y)$$where $\pi$ is the Prime Counting Function.

Observing that the Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture is equivalent to the following,

> For all $k\ge 1$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$  the following holds, $$\pi(ky)+\pi(y)\ge \pi((k+1)y)$$where $\pi$ is the Prime Counting Function.

I was wondering whether proving the following weak version of the conjecture is something significant or is it already known,

> **Proposition.** For all $k\ge 1$ there exists $M_{k}>0$ such that for all $y\ge M_{k}$ we have, $$π(ky)+π(y)>π((k+1)y)$$

I searched the internet for something similar to this but even though I found some results closely related to the above, I could't find this exact result.

So my questions are,

- Is the above proposition well-known? If so can anyone point me out to the paper/book that contains a proof of it or even better to some theorem from which this result follows?
- If not then is the proof of this result considered a significant result?

I agree that the second question may seem to be more opinionated but currently this is the best version that I can come up with.  I will be glad to receive constructive suggestions on making this question more specific and answerable

Comment: Did you mean for the conclusion of Proposition 2 to actually mention $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ doesn't appear in the displayed inequality of Proposition 2, so if I can find a $y_0$ that works at all, it's automatically true for every $\varepsilon$.  So as written there's no point in including $\varepsilon$ at all.  I assume this is not what you meant, and that there is a typo.

Comment: It seems that the first sentence in your Proposition is meant to be a condition, so you should start it with "Assume that". However, this condition follows from the Prime Number Theorem and the asymptotic expansion of $\mathrm{li}(y)$. So it seems that you are claiming the second sentence in your Proposition unconditionally, which as you remark is the second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture. Note also that this conjecture is believed to be false, as it contradicts the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture on prime tuples.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Indeed, as you wrote the first sentence is meant to be a condition (and I am aware that it follows from PNT). I am also aware that this conjecture is believed to be false by Hensley and Richard's paper. Anyway, please let me know of any other problems that you may find in this post.

Comment: As GH says, the claimed Proposition is, thanks to PNT, equivalent to the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture for all large $x,y$. This would contradict the Prime Tuple conjecture, so a) it is certainly not known and b) a proof of it would be very big news.

Comment: I suppose not equivalent, but regardless this 'weaker' form of the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture is still enough to contradict the Prime Tuple conjecture (see e.g. Theorem 7.16 in Montgomery and Vaughan)

Comment: It is not clear what the last occurrence of $y_0$ in the proposition means. If we assume that $y_0$ may depend on $k$, i.e. $\forall k\exists y_0\forall y>y_0: \pi(ky)+\pi(y)\geq\pi((k+1)y)$, then the statement does not contradict the Prime tuple conjecture. In fact, it follows from any version of the prime number theorem with an error term better than $\frac{x}{\log^2 x}$.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta: $y_0$ depends on $\varepsilon$ only and not on $k$. It is the same $y_0$ which was mentioned earlier.

Comment: But the last inequality does not contain $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta: Let me try to state the proposition a but more clearly, "Assume that for all $k>1$ and $\varepsilon\in (0,\ln \sqrt{2}]$ there exists $y_0\in \mathbb{R}$ (depending on $\varepsilon$ only) such that for all $y\ge y_0$ we have, $$\dfrac{y}{\ln y-(1-\varepsilon)}<\pi(y)<\dfrac{y}{\ln y-(1+\varepsilon)}$$Then for that $y_0$ and for all $y\ge y_0$ we have, $$\pi(ky)+\pi(y)\ge \pi((k+1)y)$$ where $\pi$ is the Prime Counting Function."

Comment: Also I don't understand which inequality you were referring. Were you referring to "$y\ge y_0$" or $\pi(ky)+\pi(y)\ge \pi((k+1)y)$? If it is the latter then can you clarify what did you mean by "the last inequality does not contain $\varepsilon"?

Comment: @user170039: It is not clear what is the role of $k$ in the first sentence of your Proposition, since $y_0$ and the first display are independent of $k$. So it seems that the "for all $k>1$" should be the beginning of the second sentence. However, even with that modification, the second statement makes no sense, as it refers to an unspecified $y_0$ (which has nothing to do with $k$). Simply put, the two sentences do not fit.

Comment: "For that y_0" does not make sense, as $y_0$ is a fuction of $\varepsilon$. Also the part about $\varepsilon$ follows from any version of the prime number theorem with error term better than $\frac{x}{\log^2 x}$.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @ThomasBloom: Just to be sure. By Montgomery and Vaughan you mean the book *Multiplicative Number Theory: I. Classical Theory*, right? Also I would be glad if you could comment on the recent version of my post.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Please let me know if there are any more mistakes in the formulation of the question.

Comment: See my response below.

Comment: I guess we are expecting the full conjecture to be false.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Not really. See Thomas Bloom's response above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not seen your proposition before, but it follows routinely from the prime number theorem.

Indeed, there exists an absolute constant $c>0$ such that
$$\pi(ky)+\pi(y)-\pi((k+1)y)=\mathrm{Li}(ky)+\mathrm{Li}(y)-\mathrm{Li}((k+1)y)+O_k\left(y e^{-c\sqrt{\log y}}\right),$$
where
$$\mathrm{Li}(ky)+\mathrm{Li}(y)-\mathrm{Li}((k+1)y)=\int_0^y\left(\frac{k}{\log(kt)}+\frac{1}{\log t}-\frac{k+1}{\log(k+1)t}\right)dt.$$
For fixed $k$ and $t\to\infty$, the integrand is
\begin{align*}&\frac{k}{\log t}\left(1-\frac{\log k+o(1)}{\log t}\right)+\frac{1}{\log t}-\frac{k+1}{\log t}\left(1-\frac{\log(k+1)+o(1)}{\log t}\right)\\[8pt]&=\frac{(k+1)\log(k+1)-k\log k+o(1)}{\log^2 t},\end{align*}
whence there exists $C_k$ such that
$$\mathrm{Li}(ky)+\mathrm{Li}(y)-\mathrm{Li}((k+1)y)\gg_k\frac{y}{\log^2 y},\qquad y\geq C_k.$$
As $\log^2 y$ grows much slower than $e^{c\sqrt{\log y}}$, we conclude that there exists $M_k$ such that
$$\pi(ky)+\pi(y)-\pi((k+1)y)\gg_k\frac{y}{\log^2 y},\qquad y\geq M_k.$$

Comment: Do the subscripts $O_k$ and $\gg_k$ just indicate that the implicit constants depend on $k$?

Comment: @MikeMiller: Yes. This is standard notation in analytic number theory.

Comment: I assumed but wanted to check. Thanks for clarifying for an outsider!

Comment: What is the best known expression for $M_k$?

Comment: @user170039: All the constants in my argument (including $c$) are effective and can be calculated by adding more detail. I leave this to you or other interested readers.